# In-place deletion of a block of lines already found in a file using perl

Tags: perl

I want to be able to locate a block of lines in a file determined by start and end keywords and then delete this block. I am using "if (/START/../END/)" to locate this block, but am not sure how to delete the lines in this block. What statement can I use inside the 'if' above to achieve this?

Note: It does not have to be true deletion. I mean, it can be simply replace the line with empty space.

PS: I am a first-time perl user and pardon me if this seems to be a stupid question. I know there are MANY similar questions out there, but no one seems to be dealing with in-place deletion and suggest options like print entire file to another file excluding the desired block.

Comment: How about simply collecting all the lines that are _not_ within /START/ .. /END/ block, then writing them into a file?

Comment: I can do that, but is there a possibility of an in-place solution at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl makes this pretty easy.

One line, in place deletion of lines between `pattern1` and `pattern2`:

```
perl -i -ne 'print unless /pattern1/../pattern2/' input_file
```

See [`perlrun`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlrun) to understand perl's  various command-line switches

Answer (score 2):

You could just invert your logic:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    print unless /START/ .. /END/;
}

=for output

foo
bar

=cut


__DATA__
foo
START
goo
END
bar
```

Comment: To do this do I need to open file in read+write mode? Will  it print all lines in the same file?

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed '/START/,/END/d' input_file
```

to modify the original file:

```
sed -i '/START/,/END/d' input_file
```